# Replace a key in an object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have:

```
var obj = {'a': {some object}, 'b': {some other object}, 'c':{some other object},...}
```

I want to write a function that will overwrite any single key in my original object.

```
myFunction(obj, {'a': {new object}});
console.log(obj);
//{'a': {new object}, 'b': {some other object}, 'c':{some other object},...}
```

I am using lodash. I obviously know that I can do `_.keys` then get the only item in the array and then assign it manually but I wonder if there is a less cumbersome way.

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs#assign ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_.extend` function, available as `Object.assign` in ES6-compatible Javascript, does what you want.

```
_.extend({ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 10 })
// { a: 10, b: 2 }
```

The function is more flexible than simple assignment: you can add or replace any number of keys, shallow-merging the objects passed as parameters.

Answer (score 3):

No need of Lodash/Underscore, this can be done in JavaScript easily.

```
obj[key] = newObject;
```

```js
var obj = {
    one: {
        1: 'ONE'
    },
    two: {
        2: 'TWO'
    },
    three: {
        3: 'THREE'
    }
};

obj['two'] = {
    22: 'Two Two'
};

console.log(obj);
```

**UPDATE:**

You can use `Object.assign()`

```
Object.assign(obj, {
    two: {
        22: 'Two Two'
    }
});
```

Comment: key changes. it's not the same each time.

Comment: @Mika When you pass dynamic key using brackets notation, it'll work.